# Reverse for 'profile_update' with arguments '(1,)' not found. Issue

Tags: django

I have a base url link to access a profile edtting screen but it seems to break my application.

Ive tried so many things that i am getting confused by the different views. I was able to get the form appearing previously but have somehow broken it.

from my base.html(if i remove this line the app start to work again).  Im not sure about this user.id parameter im passing in this - is it needed?

```
        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:profile_update' user.id %}">Edit Profile</a>
    </li>
```

my urls file:

```
 path('profile/edit/', views.ProfileCreate.as_view(), name='profile_update'),
```

my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userprofile')
    houseNumber = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    suberb = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('account:profile', kwargs=[self.pk])
```

my form:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'houseNumber', 'street', 'suberb', 'city', 'phone']
```

the html for the form:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
  <div class="container">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'accounts:profile_update' %}" method="post" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|crispy }}
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"></input>
    </form>
    <p></p>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Apologies if this question is similar to a few others Ive asked but i just had to restart with this form using a different approach because it just wasnt working properly previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you url, you don't need to pass `user.id` through `update_profile`. So please change the code to:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:profile_update' %}">Edit Profile</a>
```

Comment: Hey thanks @ruddra maybe im tired but i did try that and it didnt work. So maybe Atom text editor was making my life a misery. It works now again.